# Why does Excel suddenly find something in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba function that receives a row from a workbook and looks in come columns for data, setting variables or not depending on what is found.  For rows 2-16, everything works fine; empty cells get skipped.  Suddenly on row 17, a cell which seems empty triggers the first if-condition.

I've tried adding an additional check for cells that contain an empty string, and in the worksheet itself I checked `CODE(H17)` which was `#VALUE`

```
Function calcID(r As Long) As Variant
    If (Not IsEmpty(allProps.Cells(r, 8))) Or (Not allProps.Cells(r, 8).Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Found ID: " & allProps.Cells(r, 8).Value & " in allProps row " & r
        calcID = CDate(allProps.Cells(r, 8).Value)
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(allProps.Cells(r, 9)) Or Not allProps.Cells(r, 9).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Found reverse ID: " & allProps.Cells(r, 9).Value & " in allProps row " & r
        calcID = CDate(allProps.Cells(r, 9).Value)
    Else
        calcID = ""
    End If
End Function
```

I use CDate elsewhere and it works fine.  Ultimately the error shows up once I'm inside the `if` because I think CDate doesn't have a string to work with.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could there be a space, `" "`, or more than one space, in that cell?

Comment: My understanding is that if `=CODE(H17)` results in `#VALUE` then no, it's not a space

Comment: Is it H17 or J17? Could you check the contents in the Excel interface?

Comment: J17 is set to show the ASCII CODE representation of the contents of H17, I believe

Comment: @A.Pizzle, H17 above seems empty

Comment: ... There's your problem, your cat has dropped a ball of wool into the spreadsheet and this has tangled up all the formula! :-)

Comment: On amore serious note, select the cell and `Evaluate Formula` using the tools on the ribbon. This is an easy way to expose what is happening.

Comment: @Asger I added a variable, looks like `aVar = ""` ???

Comment: Spaces and non-printable characters would still add length to the cell's value (even though you don't see them). Instead of the checks you do, why not test for `If Len(Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(allProps.Cells(r,8)))) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only want to process the cells if they are both non-empty AND not equal to emptystring.  This will prevent strange behavior if a cell is somehow not empty but is equal to emptystring.

Change your logical ORs to ANDs.

```
Function calcID(r As Long) As Variant
    If (Not IsEmpty(allProps.Cells(r, 8))) And (Not allProps.Cells(r, 8).Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Found ID: " & allProps.Cells(r, 8).Value & " in allProps row " & r
        calcID = CDate(allProps.Cells(r, 8).Value)
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(allProps.Cells(r, 9)) And Not allProps.Cells(r, 9).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Found reverse ID: " & allProps.Cells(r, 9).Value & " in allProps row " & r
        calcID = CDate(allProps.Cells(r, 9).Value)
    Else
        calcID = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the value in the cell which starts with = is taken as formula in excel.

For eg : =test is taken as a formula with error like this in excel.

[image]

I do had a similar issue and sorted it out by comparing the value in the cell and trimming off unwanted = in cell value.
Please make sure you are not getting any value in that cell which makes excel think that it is a formula or cell reference.

Comment: There is no "=" in cell H17; I've clicked in the cell and hit delete, etc.

Comment: Can you please get the run time value of the cell by debugging your code?

Comment: looks like `calcID = Empty`